# Snowflake - Casting Variant to Float with possible empty strings

Tags: casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've combed thru the docs but can't seem to find a more straightforward way to convert one of our T-SQL queries to Snowflake.  I'm trying to parse out a value in JSON, cast it as a float, and if the value is an empty string, assign it to zero.

In T-SQL, it's:

`cast(JSON_VALUE(fieldName, '$."json.path.to.value"') as float)`

In Snowflake, an empty string will give an error, so you need to use a cast try.  The cast try doesn't support variant, only a string.  If a try fails, it returns a null.  So I get something like this:

`coalesce(try_to_double(to_varchar(parse_json(fieldName):"json.path.to.value")),0)`

That works, but the four nested functions seem a little over done.  Is there a simpler way for this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your JSON that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sure, I changed the attributes a little bit, but using the example I provided above, it would be something like: 

"json" : {
  "path" :  {
    "to" : { 
      "value" : "343.2"
    }
  }
}

...where value is often a real in a string, but sometimes an empty string.

Comment: in the update you give, your example solution `coalesce(try_to_double(to_varchar(parse_json(fieldName):"json.path.to.value")),0)` doesn't actual work with this input. Which is why I pointed this out in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming fieldName is already a VARIANT, then you shouldn't need the `parse_json`.  And I'd shorten things up with:

```
SELECT IFNULL(TRY_TO_DOUBLE(fieldName:path:to:value::varchar),0)
FROM ... ;
```

Comment: You can also use the ZEROIFNULL function as an alternative to IFNULL.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - the source database (MSSQL) is storing this as a varchar(max).  I'm bringing it over using Stitch which stores it as a VARCHAR(16777216), which is why I'm parsing.

Comment: All these examples are helpful, I appreciate the discussion. I think the best combination in terms of brevity and explicitness from what I'm hearing would be: 


`ZEROIFNULL(TRY_TO_DOUBLE(PARSE_JSON(fieldName):json:path:to:value::varchar))`

Comment: I was unaware of ZEROIFNULL function, but that certainly does help condense things.  Thank you @GregPavlik.

Comment: `COALESCE(,0)`  12 chars, `IFNULL(,0)` 10 chars, `ZEROIFNULL()` 12 chars... _so it adds ZERO value_ hahaha but might be more explicit.

Comment: also the only case where ` fieldName:json:path:to:value` works is the same case as `json.path.to.value` which I showed, and in that case the given "it works" example doesn't work..

Comment: and all the while if we are counting bytes use `::text` over `::varchar` as it's 3 bytes shorter.

Comment: I don't think anybody was counting bytes.  The OP was referencing the number of functions needed.  Your comparison of the different functions are equivalent in that regard, so just a matter of preference.  I liked the ZEROIFNULL() for the readability of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the T-SQL is three, four steps seems fine.

I would swap the `to_varchar()` for the `::text` like

```
coalesce(try_to_double(parse_json(fieldName):"json.path.to.value"::text),0)
```

also to the json question if you object looks like:

```
{
   "json.path.to.value":10
}
```

then the form you have will work, but if you actually have a nested objects like:

```
{
    json:{
        path:{
            to:{
                value:66
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you will want `parse_json(fieldName):json.path.to.value::text`

as can be seen by:

```
select 
   coalesce(try_to_double(to_varchar(parse_json(fieldName):"json.path.to.value")),0)
   ,coalesce(try_to_double(parse_json(fieldName):"json.path.to.value"::text),0)
   ,coalesce(try_to_double(parse_json(fieldName):json.path.to.value::text),0)
from values 
   ('{"json.path.to.value":0.1}'), 
   ('{"json.path.to.value":10}'),
   ('{"json.path.to.value":"not a float"}'),
   ('{json:{path:{to:{value:66}}}}'),
   ('{"different_field_name":51}')
   v(fieldName);
```

gives:

```
0.1 0.1 0
10  10  0
0   0   0
0   0   66
0   0   0
```

Comment: the TSQL is only two steps (JSON_VALUE and CAST), but I think they just got "lucky" in the old code, in that the analyst wanted zero to be the default with missing data and that's what T-SQL provides.  Personally I like the defaulting to error, then null - 0 could be meaningful and if it fails like that silently that could cause problems if it wasn't the intended results.